# Active the sub menu all li first-child on hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Digital</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
       </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

Whenever  over on the Services menu than show  li as well as sub  and when mouse out from services its none.

Comment: What have you tried in JavaScript to realize this?

Comment: Have you tried this https://css-tricks.com/targetting-menu-elements-submenus-navigation-bar/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code as example.

Add your own creative CSS to make it unique.

```css
  nav {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .nav a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.8em 1.8em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
  .nav li {
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav > li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
  }
  .nav > li > a {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
  }

  /* submenu positioning*/
  .nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -99999em;
  }
  .nav > li:hover > ul {
    left: auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Digital</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Digital</a><ul class=="subMenu"><li>All Design</li></ul></li>
          <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
       </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
</ul>      sumMenu also open on hover services menu